# Convert the code in function component to class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having this react js code and I am trying to convert the following code into class component

I don't know how to do that if someone can create a working sandbox then it will be helpful

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Jane",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: "25"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "James",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: "40"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Alexa",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: "27"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "Jane",
    lastName: "Brown",
    age: "40"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [peopleInfo, setPeopleInfo] = useState({});

  const toggleHandler = (item) => () => {
    setPeopleInfo((state) => ({
      ...state,
      [item.id]: state[item.id]
        ? null
        : {
            id: item.id,
            first: item.name,
            last: item.lastName,
            age: item.age
          }
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(peopleInfo);
  }, [peopleInfo]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tr>
          {data.map((item) => {
            return (
              <div
                key={item.id}
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  width: "150px"
                }}
              >
                <input
                  onChange={toggleHandler(item)}
                  checked={peopleInfo[item.id]}
                  style={{ margin: "20px" }}
                  type="checkbox"
                />
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.name}</td>
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.lastName}</td>
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.age}</td>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am having this react js code and I am trying to convert the following code into a class component

I don't know how to do that if someone can create a working sandbox then it will be helpful
I am having this react js code and I am trying to convert the following code into a class component

I don't know how to do that if someone can create a working sandbox then it will be helpful

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to convert a functional component into a class component? Most people want to do the exact opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method corresponds to `useEffect` hook.
2. The `render` method should return the JSX to be rendered from the class component.
3. `this.setState` method is available by extending the `Component` class (from prototype chaining).

This will be the corresponding class component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Jane",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: "25"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "James",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: "40"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Alexa",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: "27"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "Jane",
    lastName: "Brown",
    age: "40"
  }
];

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {};

  toggleHandler = (item) => () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      [item.id]: state[item.id]
        ? null
        : {
            id: item.id,
            first: item.name,
            last: item.lastName,
            age: item.age
          }
    }));
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <table>
          <tr>
            {data.map((item) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={item.id}
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    width: "150px"
                  }}
                >
                  <input
                    onChange={this.toggleHandler(item)}
                    checked={this.state[item.id]}
                    style={{ margin: "20px" }}
                    type="checkbox"
                  />
                  <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.name}</td>
                  <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.lastName}</td>
                  <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.age}</td>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit practical-keller-nby4s0]

Answer (score 0):

ComponentDidUpdate will be called when each it rerender with state update.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Jane",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: "25"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "James",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: "40"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Alexa",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: "27"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "Jane",
    lastName: "Brown",
    age: "40"
  }
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    peopleInfo: {}
  };

  toggleHandler(item) {
    this.setState({
      peopleInfo: {
        ...this.state.peopleInfo,
        [item.id]: this.state.peopleInfo[item.id]
          ? null
          : {
              id: item.id,
              first: item.name,
              last: item.lastName,
              age: item.age
            }
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.state.peopleInfo);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <table>
          <tr>
            {data.map((item) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={item.id}
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    width: "150px"
                  }}
                >
                  <input
                    onChange={() => this.toggleHandler(item)}
                    checked={this.state.peopleInfo[item.id]}
                    style={{ margin: "20px" }}
                    type="checkbox"
                  />
                  <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.name}</td>
                  <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.lastName}</td>
                  <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.age}</td>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-sutherland-yo7s9w?file=/src/App.js)